# NoReverseMatch (with multiple redirect() calls)

Tags: python, django

I have two functions in my views.py file that have a `redirect('account')` call if user is logged in.

Django throws the following error:

```
Reverse for 'account' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

However if I remove the `redirect()` call from any one of them , it works.
What should i do?

Django 1.3.1, Python 2.7.2

Answer (score 1):

You should create a urlconf entry with the name "account" that takes no parameters from the URL. Or maybe you should pass any required parameters to the function.